# Label inadvertently disappearing after certain length

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, label

I have a fairly large (width wise) C# WinForms Application that uses a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` inside a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` as a Marquee.

A `System.Timers.Timer` updates the `Label` position after a tick event.

```
int new_X_location = (label.Location.X + distance_invariant) % modulo;
label.Location = new Point(new_X_location, label.Location.Y);
```

The functionality of the marquee is not the issue, 
when I change the `Label.Text` field, the label disappears!

```
string some_string = working_function_that_returns_string();
label.Text = some_string; //disappears!
```

[image]

It seems to be limited to a length of about 2100 characters or so when the font size is large (`24pt`). When it is smaller (`10pt`) the string can be much longer (`label.Text.Length >= 4200`).

```
string some_string = working_function_that_returns_string();
label.Text = some_string.SubString(0,2000); //it's still visibile here.
...
label.Text = some_string.SubString(0,2200) //it's not visible!
```

I am not sure if it has to do with Width limitations or Font size limitations <strike>or a Form width positioning.</strike>. Positioning is correct at smaller font sizes and shorter strings. Therefore it is not a positioning error.

Comment: Could you please post relevant code and/or pictures of your problem?

Comment: Don't ever use System.Timers.Timer to do anything with a control.  Set the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property back to true.

Comment: I am taking care of that with `InvokeRequired` and `.Invoke()` thank you. There are no problems in that regard.

Comment: just added more code. hope it clears the question up.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, also with very long labels, and also in a marquee. Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: @DTI-Matt, make custom label, if text is too long - split drawing.

Comment: But how can I possibly know when the text is too long? What is making it too long? Why is this a restriction in the first place?

Comment: I don't know why, but after posting this, I seemed to resolve the problem by changing the size of the font, this could be useful to someone with more knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a test application to check and I think the problem is related to the use of `GDI+` and the hardware acceleration this library make use of. On my PC a width greater than 8192 pixels do not renders correctly (the label disappear like in your case when I change text).

Setting the property `UseCompatibleTextRendering` of the label (and so using `GDI` and not `GDI+`) the text render almost correctly, but *some glyphs fragments are visibile on the bottom side of the label*.

You must break your label into several labels:

- try to break up the label in chuncks not greater than 8192 pixels.
- if your text is composed of various periods, you could create a label for each period (it is a faster and easier).

This is the test code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LabelMaxChars
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Panel pnlStrip;
        private Label lblText;
        private Timer timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pnlStrip = new Panel();
            pnlStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            pnlStrip.Height = 64;
            pnlStrip.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            pnlStrip.ForeColor = Color.White;

            lblText = new Label();
            lblText.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0f, FontStyle.Regular, 
                                    GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lblText.Location = new Point(582, 6);
            lblText.AutoSize = true;
            lblText.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
            lblText.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "+
                            "Sed vestibulum elit ac nunc feugiat, non varius enim commodo. "+
                            "Etiam congue, massa sollicitudin congue dapibus, odio erat blandit "+
                            "lectus, non vehicula nisi lacus sed orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis "+
                            "in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec ullamcorper "+
                            "feugiat dui, at imperdiet elit pulvinar in. Sed ac fermentum massa. "+
                            "Mauris hendrerit magna sit amet mi eleifend fringilla. "+
                            "Donec pretium augue gravida enim fermentum placerat. "+
                            "Vestibulum malesuada nisl a odio imperdiet condimentum. Sed vitae neque nulla. "+
                            "Curabitur sed facilisis odio. Integer adipiscing, ante ac cursus dignissim, "+
                            "ante sapien auctor ligula, id faucibus elit mauris nec nulla. "+
                            "Sed elementum nisl id quam convallis dictum. Nullam nulla turpis, "+
                            "elementum ac nisi in, faucibus eleifend est. ";

            lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
            lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
            lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
            lblText.Text += lblText.Text;

            Console.WriteLine("Text length {0}", lblText.Text.Length);

            pnlStrip.Controls.Add(lblText);
            this.Controls.Add(pnlStrip);

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 10;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            --lblText.Left;
            if (lblText.Left == this.ClientSize.Width >> 1)
            {
                lblText.Text = "Nullam id nisl tortor. Donec in commodo magna. Integer dignissim vestibulum ipsum, " +
                "ac lobortis nisl faucibus ac. Pellentesque convallis placerat est, " +
                "non tempus mi scelerisque in. Sed vel aliquam tellus. " +
                "Donec tincidunt elit et imperdiet egestas. Cras vel dictum lacus. " +
                "Nullam mollis neque ac lectus congue, eget imperdiet risus feugiat. " +
                "In commodo odio quis purus scelerisque, ut vestibulum justo vulputate. " +
                "Proin sit amet facilisis libero. Donec mollis, enim at ultrices rhoncus, " +
                "quam lectus condimentum ante, a varius urna nisl rutrum mi. " +
                "Pellentesque sodales tincidunt suscipit. Cras semper sem vulputate, " +
                "ornare eros sed, fringilla libero. Sed risus turpis, mollis vitae dictum eu, " +
                "malesuada et magna. Etiam quis orci nunc. Morbi mattis ante a nibh hendrerit vehicula. ";

                lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
                lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
                lblText.Text += lblText.Text;
                lblText.Text += lblText.Text;

                Console.WriteLine("Text length {0}", lblText.Text.Length);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having a fixed sized lable (`AutoSize` false) with [AutoEllipsis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis.aspx) property true? If its due to width limitation or wrapping issues then it should go away.

If that doesn't solve the issue then you might want to look at the positioning code. If it is using the label width in position calculation then the width changes due to text change might throw some surprises at some corner cases. Again, having fixed size label (or having some max size) may help.

Comment: I actually would like the exact opposite, (`AutoSize = true`, `AutoEllipsis = false`). I did try what you said and the text does not disappear but it appears very short since it doesnt resize. that would  seem to mean positioning is ok.

Comment: @user1934851, what is the label size value at the lengthier text? Determine the threshold (of label size or text size) and switch to `AutoSize = false, AutoEllipsis = true`. Yet another way would be allowing text-wrapping by increasing height but its more tedious than the previous option.

Comment: Even if I remove the tick event, making the label stationary, the problem remains. Can you please be more specific about "text-wrapping by increasing height"?

Comment: @user1934851, I was just wondering whether the label text has wrapped and hence could not be seen - so you need to increase height with auto-size off so that lengthier text would get wrapped within the whatever limited max width you would set. But increasing height for a marquee can become issue from layout perspective... I would rather go with ellipsis.

Comment: I agree that this is the easier choice, and works as I have already tried it, but that means moving text one char at a time, and gives a very staggered motion for a Marquee. Moving the label itself seemed the obvious alternative, as the resolution of movement can be controlled by pixel. Unless you know how to move text inside a label on a per pixel basis...

Answer (score 0):

I am also using something like this! Try this:

```
label1.Size = CreateGraphics().MeasureString(label_txt, label1.Font).ToSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use break points  to that function.

```
(brkpnt)|    string some_string = working_function_that_returns_string();
```

then while debugging "step in" that function.
 debug it step by step.
check variables from autos windows.
it may have LOGICAL MISTAKE that returns "" empty string .

you gotta post that  working_function_that_returns_string();

**other İdea** . you may modify  textbox.bacgorundcolor to none to make it look like label

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to resolve the error:

```
// Try disabling the "AutoSize"-property, and use the panels' sizes
label.AutoSize = false;
label.Width = yourRedPanel.Width;
label.Height = yourRedPanel.Height;
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
label.AutoEllipsis = true;

// Check that "new_X_location"-variable is not negative or 
// too big to move the label out of the viewable area
label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(new_X_location, label.Location.Y);

// Check that some_string.Length is as great or greater than given Substring length argument
label.Text = some_string.Substring(0, 2200);

// The max font size is the biggest possible value of float
Font testFont = new Font("Arial", float.MaxValue);

// If this doesn't help, wrap your code to try-catch block
// Run the code line by line (F10), and see where it jumps to "catch",
// if there occurs errors
try
{
   // Code here
}
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```